# How to write a function in ORACLE to translate English to other Language

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hello My dear Techies,

I need to understand if there is way to create a function in Oracle that input the text in English and output in Spanish/French etc...

Can we utilize any Open source Translate tool(via Web URL) in our PLSQL Function for this conversion ?

I know this can be done via PYTHON but not sure how to do in Oracle.

Regards,
Pramod

Comment: Have a look at what Solomon and Barbara did at this OraFAQ Forum discussion: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/170320

Comment: Hello Littlefoot, Yes i saw the post but i am not able to understand below statement where it ask to create ACL, What and why we have to do this :--                                        
 "we need to create and assign ACLs in order to access web sites."

Comment: ACL (Access Control List).  Define who can access what sites. You would not want anyone accessing any site.